# FLS in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom controller page

```
<apex:page controller="Cust1" tabStyle="Account">
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageblock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}">

  You belong to account {!accounti.name}
  Change its name 
  <apex:inputField value="{!accounti.name}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
  </apex:pageblock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and associated controller class

```
public class Cust1 {
public Account accounti{get;set;}

public cust1()
{

Accounti = [select name from account where id = :ApexPages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
}

public pagereference save()
{
return null;
}
}
```

When i run this as a user who doesnt have edit permission for account, my input field appears as read only..
My understanding was custom controllers run in 'system-mode' It doesn't respect CRUD/FLS
So why is this coming as 'read-only?

Answer (score 9):

This [Enforcing CRUD and FLS](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS) documentation includes the explanation and a work-around (though you lose other features of `apex:inputField` too):

> VisualForce will also remove fields for which users do not have FLS
>   visibility when rendering edit pages. Additionally, all
>   apex:inputField tags will be rendered as read-only elements for fields
>   that are set to read-only through FLS. Please note that using other
>   input tags such as apex:inputText or apex:inputTextArea with SObject
>   fields indicate to VisualForce that the fields should not be treated
>   as SObject fields and prevent the platform to automatically enforcing
>   FLS.

Comment: so irrespective of whether its standard controller/custom controller(usermode/system mode) if its apex:inputfield or apex:outputfield on page--then FLS/CRUD is enforced?

Comment: @sfdc99999 AFAIK yes. Its a (non-optional) feature of the apex:inputField Visualforce tag and presumably also the apex:outputField tag. The behaviour mirrors how layout-based UI works. Its independent of how the data was queried.